# Comando adb abrir URL do youtube via Browser

Tags: android, shell, sdk

Para iniciar uma URL via adb, tenho o seguinte comando adb shell:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'https://youtu.be/CSULRDoF8-g'
```

Que funciona. Mas no caso de uma URL de um video do YouTube, a URL é aberta pela app do YouTube. Eu gostaria que abrisse pelo Chrome ou pelo Internet

Como fazer isso adaptando o comando ou usando algum outro similar? Estou usando um Galaxy S7 da Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito eu que o único jeito é desabilitando os padrões de *links*. No caso basta procurar por "Padrões" nas configurações do aparelho e desabilitar o do YouTube, assim cada vez que requisitar um *link* do YouTube, o aparelho vai perguntar em qual *app* quer abrir o *link*.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de testar aqui:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9JmJBn3p9g
```